# Eclipse Plugin: Order of Native Libraries in the "Bundle-NativeCode" Section

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox

Recall the `Bundle-NativeCode` section in `MAINFEST.MF`:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: 
  lib/windows/x64/Library1.dll;
  lib/windows/x64/Library2.dll;
  ...
  osname=win32; processor=x86_64
```

In fact, I have around a hundred of libraries there. What I found out is that depending on the order they are specified, the plugin might fail to load with the following message:

```
!MESSAGE Missing native code match lib/windows/x64/Library1.dll; lib/windows/x64/Library2.dll; ...
```

At first, I thought that the reason might be the dependencies between native libraries themselves. In other words, I thought that maybe OSGi expects me to list these native libraries in the order of their dependency, i.e. the most independent ones first. After a few hours of that kind of sorting of a hundred of libraries according to their order, it again failed miserably, what proves that this is not the reason. I have one magical order which was found by chance, when it loads successfully, and it does not resemble any pattern, it is absolutely random order. If I start changing it, then the chance is high that it will fail again. For example, I want to sort them alphabetically, and this will not work.

Could anybody clarfiy what's going on. I've already wasted quite a lot of time on this issue and I'm very confused how on Earth can this happen at all and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order does not matter. Since you have so many libraries. make sure you use ";" to separate them. Using "," will start a new clause that may cause an error if there are not matching attributes on the clause.

Comment: Yes, I know about these rules. It's all fine. Still the weird problem with order remains. In the meantime I will be double checking everything.